# Get payments for an account for an asset

Tags: horizon, accounts, assets, payments

Is there a way to query horizon to get payment operations for an account and for a certain asset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query payments for a given account but there is no way to filter by asset:

https://developers.stellar.org/api/resources/accounts/payments/